# SQL Get every nth row from a column to be assigned to a new column

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops

I've been working on a timely dataset where I have Dates, UserNumber, and District name. I need to create a new column where I can get the value from last week's user number for each district.
I made a temp table where it gives a row number for each District order by ascending Date so I can get the value by (rn + 7).

```
for example
```

| date | state | rn | user_number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-09-12 | Florida | 1 | 22901 |
| 2022-09-11 | Florida | 2 | 1723 |
| 2022-09-10 | Florida | 3 | 2918 |
| 2022-09-09 | Florida | 4 | 12213 |
| 2022-09-08 | Florida | 5 | 7182 |

```
result:
```

| date | state | rn | user_number | last_week_user |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-09-12 | Florida | 1 | 22901 | (1+7)th user_number |
| 2022-09-11 | Florida | 2 | 1723 | (2+7)th user_number |
| 2022-09-10 | Florida | 3 | 2918 | (3+7)th user_number |
| 2022-09-09 | Florida | 4 | 12213 | (4+7)th user_number |
| 2022-09-08 | Florida | 5 | 7182 | (5+7)th user_number |

I've tried to use CTE and over partition by:

```
With cte As
(
SELECT 
date, state, rn, user_number, last_week_user, ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by [state] order by rn asc) lw
FROM dbo.['WA DL Thp$']
WHERE rn % 7 = 1
)
UPDATE cte SET  last_week_user = user_number
```

But the output only gives me a value for the current week. Is there a way I could iterate through every row with the initial start is for each row in the user_number column?

Comment: small hint to start with, try using `self join` with `dateadd` function. As @KenWhite rightly said, show us your efforts, if you get stuck , SO community is here to help.

Comment: Yes thank you, I just forgot to add my codes. I've been working on this problem for a couple of days. I apologize for that.